# VBA Excel - Assigning multiple values to an array using a single variable

Tags: vba, excel

For my issue i have checked the archive and there is a similar thread but my issue is slightly different and i cant seem to be able to tweak my code to make it work.
The similar one is here: [Excel 2010 VBA: How to store an array of worksheets as a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169208/excel-2010-vba-how-to-store-an-array-of-worksheets-as-a-variable)

I am trying to assign a series of tabs to an array using a variable. The variable uses a value in a cell on another sheet.

```
Dim VendorTabsArray As Variant

VendorTabs= Sheets("OtherSheet").Range("A1").Value
VendorTabsArray = Array(VendorTabs)

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(VendorTabsArray).Select
```

The actual value in the cell A1 i wish to use as variable to put into the tab array is **"EBS - Add User", "EBS - Modify User", "EBS - Delete User", "EBS - Re-Enable User", "EBS - Password Reset", "EBS - Access Profiles Roles", "EBS - Reporting"**

This give me a Subscript out of range error.

When i add a watch to VendorTabArray, it does not seem to recognize the quotes and commas in the variable and just adds the whole list of tabs into the first array position instead of splitting them out.

Does any know how i can select these tabs using an array from a variable whereby the variable is a cell reference that contains all required tabs?

Any help is very much appreciated as it has me baffled.

Comment: Let me see if I have this correct and then try to help you: Cell "A1" contains that whole string of tabs? All of those words are in one cell and you want to store each individual one in one entry of the array?

Comment: Why is it that you want them to all be stored in A1 instead of just manually typed out in the macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with something small that works:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim someArray As Variant
    someArray = Array("EBS - Add User", "EBS - Modify User")        
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(someArray).Select

End Sub
```

Then try to read from the worksheet and localize the problem:

[image]

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim someString As String
    someString = Range("A1")

    Dim someArray As Variant
    someArray = Split(someString, ",")

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(someArray).Select

End Sub
```

The problem is visible in the values of someArray:

[image]

Then you need some "cleaning". Thus, you create a second array, which removes the useless `"` and trims a bit the values:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim someString As String
    someString = Range("A1")

    Dim someArray As Variant
    someArray = Split(someString, ",")

    Dim someNewArray As Variant
    ReDim someNewArray(UBound(someArray))
    Dim cnt As Long

    For cnt = LBound(someNewArray) To UBound(someNewArray)
        someNewArray(cnt) = Trim(Replace(someArray(cnt), """", ""))
    Next cnt

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(someNewArray).Select

End Sub
```

Now it works:

[image]

Comment: Thank you all. I used the Split command to assign each item in my string separated by comma to an element in the array. This worked perfect. For the quotation clean up, i just removed them from the variable so a second array for this wasn't required. Thank you all again for your help. I am very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a split function. It will read a string and split the string at certain characters and store each split as an entry of an array base (0). See below:

```
Dim VendorTabs, VendorTabsArray As Variant

VendorTabs = Sheets("Other Sheet").Range("A1").Value
VendorTabsArray = Split(VendorTabs, ",")
For t = LBound(VendorTabsArray) To UBound(VendorTabsArray)
    VendorTabsArray(t) = Trim(VendorTabsArray(t))
    MsgBox VendorTabsArray(t)
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(VendorTabsArray(t)).Select
Next
```

This sets a variable equal to the cell that contains every tab, then the split function automatically creates an array base (0) with the entries and stores it at the specified variable you give it. Then we use the For-loop to run through the lower bound of the array (0) to the upper bound (however many tabs you have minus 1), we trim the array values (to get rid of the extra space before and after commas) and then the message box simply prints what the array value is. This exists so you can check to see if the array is working properly.

You can replace the message box with any functionality you want the array to do. I don't believe you specified what you wanted to do once the array was created, but whatever you want to do, that's where you'd put the code.

**UPDATE:** I see where you'd like it to select the worksheets of the tab array. I've added that to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Say we have a cell with sheet names in this format:

[image]

This code gets an array of those sheet names:

```
Sub ArrayOfSheetNames()
    Dim arr
    arr = Split(Replace(Range("D26").Value, Chr(34), ""), ",")
End Sub
```

We remove the double-quotes and split on comma.